# Links Not Appearing Over Image When Moused Over

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, mouseover, rollover

I have a rollover image, and the goal is that when the user mouses over the image, it darkens (which I achieved using a rollover image) and two links appear titled "learn more" and "visit site" (they should appear over the image). Before I get to styling I wanted to make sure everything was working properly, and my issue is that the links don't seem to appear at all. What am I doing wrong that I should fix to be able to see the links when the image is moused over?

The website with the issue is [here](http://tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/web_design.html#good_examples) and you can see if you mouse over one of the images how the link doesn't appear. My code is below.

HTML

```
<div id="example1" class="good_example"><a onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"  onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('ABC','','images/examples/abc_website_over.png',1)"><img  src="images/examples/abc_website_desat.png" alt="visit site" width="300" height="200"  id="ABC"></a>
<div class="options">
<a href="http://www.example.com">Learn More</a><a href="#good_examples" id="click-me1">Visit Site</a>
</div></div>
```

CSS

```
#example1:hover.options {
visibility:visible;
}

.options {
visibility:hidden;  
position:absolute;
z-index:9999999;
top:50px;
left:75px;
}

.options a:link {
padding-right:15px; 
padding-left:15px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
margin:10px;
color:#ffffff;
font-size:40px;

border-radius:10px;

-webkit-border-radius:10px;

-moz-border-radius:10px;
width:50px; 
text-align:center;
opacity:0.7;
background-color:#069;
}

.options a:hover {
opacity:1;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with your `css` selector

```
#example1:hover.options {
visibility:visible;
}
```

Replace the selector to something like this:

```
#example1:hover > .options {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

and that should work.

[here's a quick sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Q39w5/)

Answer (score 0):

you have .options {visibility:hidden;} so it is unseen no matter what content in it. you should at least change it to visible when .options:hover.